# Вывести элементы массива с четными индексами

Tags: python

Задача:

Дан массив, состоящий из целых чисел. Нумерация элементов начинается с 0. Напишите программу, которая выведет элементы массива, номера которых четны (0, 2, 4...).

Входные данные
Сначала задано число N — количество элементов в массиве. Далее через пробел записаны N чисел — элементы массива. Массив состоит из целых чисел.

Выходные данные
Необходимо вывести все элементы массива с чётными номерами.

```
n = int(input())
mass = list(map(int, input().split()))
for i in range(0, n-1):
    elem = mass[i]
    index = i
    if index % 2 == 0:
        print(mass[index], end = ' ')
```

Программа выдает не те элементы. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку

Comment: зачем вам цикл? `print(*mass[::2])`

Comment: @MaxU Добавьте это как ответ. Проголосую за ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того чтобы обратиться к элементам списка через N элементов (через два в вашем случае), удобнее всего воспользоваться [срезом (`slice`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation):

Пример:

```
In [52]: mass = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

печатаем четные элементы:

```
In [53]: print(*mass[::2])
10 12 14 16 18
```

нечетные элементы:

```
In [54]: print(*mass[1::2])
11 13 15 17 19
```

каждый третий элемент, начиная с нулевого:

```
In [55]: print(*mass[::3])
10 13 16 19
```

каждый третий элемент, начиная с третьего:

```
In [56]: print(*mass[2::3])
12 15 18
```